# Is it possible to create a service that connects to VSTS without using a PAT?

Tags: authentication, azure-devops, access-token

I followed the guidance that Microsoft had around creating a Node.js pull request status server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server?view=vsts

The guidance requires that a Personal Access Token (PAT) is used to authenticate the application. The problem is that the PAT can only be set to a maximum of a year before expiration. I'm worried that we will forget when the token expires and we will start seeing errors in our PR process, and then we will have to get a new token and redeploy the application with that new token.

Is there an alternative that will allow the server to authenticate based on approved applications or user account or etc? How is it possible for Visual Studio to work so well with VSTS without requiring PATs?

If it helps, we plan to host the server in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few methods to authorize:

[image]

Try this:

```
let authHandler = azdev.getNtlmHandler("username","password");
```

Or this:

```
let authHandler = azdev.getBasicHandler("username","password");
```

(For basic authentication you need to enable it also in the IIS - not recommended).

Note: maybe the `username` should be with the domain (`domain\username`).